# n unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "CREATE"

Tags: python, sql, jenkins, db2

Hi I have a long sql query and am using python to execute the query to DB2, i am passing the query as a string parameter on jenkins job

I am getting the below:

```
       connectToServer(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4])
       File "mavisdb2scripts.py", line 10, in connectToServer
       stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, sqlquery)
       Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT"     was found following "CREATE".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".
           SQLSTATE=42601 SQLCODE=-104
```

sys.argv[4] is the sql query... some how it take the first string instead of the whole string query... i tried pass it directly on the code and it works fine also try using qoutes/double

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: The SQL that Db2 receives is malformed in some way, but you do not show the SQL.  It if is coming from a command-line, then quoting and special characters are often the cause. DEBUG your code , show exactly the SQL before it gets sent to Db2 (which is different from how it may appear to you on command line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds, it does not pick up multiple lines.  So try to write your SQL in one line only by removing return code from end of all lines.
If you want to use multiple lines still, try to add backslach sign '\' at the end of all lines.

Hope this helps.